# How to realize this in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

There is a matrix `X`, the size of which is 400-by-1000. I want to collect L = 10 samples, each of size M = 500, drawn without replacement from a uniform distribution over `X`. How to realize it by using Matlab? Anyone can give me a help?

Comment: I don't know but I could imagine it would be because you didn't include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your question is not that well defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing would be to use [`randsample`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html) from the statistics toolbox.  This allows you to take a random sample from a population / data without replacement.  However, `randsample` takes in **a vector**, but you want to sample from a matrix.  Judging from the context, each element in this matrix is equally likely to be chosen, so if we simply convert the matrix into a vector and we sample from this vector, you should achieve the same result.

If you want 10 samples of length 500, you can either call `randsample` once and get 5000 samples from the matrix, and reshape this into a 10 x 500 matrix where each row represents one 500 element sample, or loop this call 10 times and concatenate the results at each call.

So you can do this:

```
Y = randsample(X(:), 5000);
Y = reshape(Y, 10, 500);
```

The above code generates a 5000 x 1 vector and we reshape it into a 10 x 500 matrix.

Or you can do this:

```
Y = [];
for idx = 1 : 10 
    Y = [Y randsample(X(:), 500)];
end
Y = Y.';
```

`randsample` generates a 500 x 1 vector at each call, so we will stack these column vectors horizontally, then transpose the result so we get a 10 x 500 matrix.

---

However, if you don't have `randsample`, you can use [`randperm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) to generate a random permutation of numbers from 1 to `400 x 1000`, and select 5000 elements from this permutation.  You can then index into `X` to obtain your final matrix.  Something like:

```
idx = randperm(400*1000, 5000);
Y = reshape(X(idx), 10, 500);
```